# Making input unfocusable, tabindex="-1" doesn't do the job

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a number and text inputs unfocusable using tabindex="-1", however it doesn't seem to work as I am still able to focus in and change values, where as I want to use custom made controls for this.

Comment: tabindex doesn't make things unfocusable, it only sets the ...... wait for it ....... tab index. If you want to disable the element, use `disabled`, if you want to make it read only, well use that etc.

Comment: you can disable the input, and if you dont like the disabled color or you dont want that, then change it in css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could stop the tab for the input field with jquery.

```
$('input').on('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.which == 9) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

greetins timmi

Comment: What does this do to users that rely on keyboard navigation?